# Push content from Parse to iOS app at intervals

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I currently get data from `Parse`, which refreshes when `viewDidLoad` or pull-to-refresh happens in a `PFQueryTableViewController`:

```
    [self.getBackFromParse()]
```

Is there any way to **set up an interval on `Parse`s end to push content to the iOS app**?

For example, set `Parse` up to push all new data to the iOS app every 24 hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could create `UILocalNotification`in the **background** where every 24 hours it executes a queryFromParse.

Comment: That makes sense to me.  Thanks for the help again!

Comment: And also, if you happen to have a chance to see if you have an answer to this by chance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442129/passing-dictionary-to-watch-using-background-transfer-via-application-context